The axiom of choice - when and why to use it
I am a bit confused because I don't fully understand when the axiom of choice can be used and when it cannot. Here is the definition of AC that interests me - it relies purely on sets (and importantly for me, it does not use the concept of functions):
For every family $S$ of non-empty disjoint sets, there exists a set $V$ (a so-called "selector"), which contains exactly one element from each of the sets belonging to the family $S$..
Formally:
$$\forall_{S} \Big\{\big[\forall_{X \in\, S} X \ne \varnothing\big]\! \land\! \big[\forall_{X, Y \in\, S}\, (X \ne Y \Rightarrow X \cap Y = \varnothing)\big] \Rightarrow \exists_V \forall_{X \in\, S}\, \exists_x \big(X \cap V = \{x\}\big)\Big\}$$
Notation:
$(a,b) = \{a, \{a,b\}\}$ - Kuratowski short ordered pair for elements
$(a;b)$ - Open interval in  $\mathbb R$
(i.e., , denotes a pair, and ; denotes an interval)
$[a;b]$ - Closed interval in $\mathbb R$
$(a_i)_{i=1}^{n}=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) = \{ (1,a_1), (2,a_2), (3,a_3),..., (n,a_n)\}$ , for $n>2$ - Finite sequence
$(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}=(a_1,a_2,...) = \{ (1,a_1), (2,a_2), (3,a_3),...\}$ , for $n>2$ - Infinite sequence
$\mathbb Z'$  is a certain subset of $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb R'$ is a certain subset of $\mathbb R$
Description
Now let me cite the following examples of families of sets:
$$\begin{align}
A &= \{ \{a\}: a \in \mathbb{Z}' \}  \\
B &= \{ \{a,b\}: a,b \in \mathbb{Z}' \}  \\
C_n &= \{ \{a_1, a_2,..., a_n\}: a_i \in \mathbb{Z}' \}  \\
C  &= \{ \{a_1, a_2,..., a_n\}: a_i \in \mathbb{Z}', n\in\mathbb{N} \}  \\
D &= \{ \{a_1, a_2,...\}: a_i \in \mathbb{Z}', \}  \\
\\
E &= \{ (a,b): a,b \in \mathbb{Z}' \}  \\
F_n &= \{ (a_1,a_2,...,a_n): a_i \in \mathbb{Z}' \} \\
F &= \{ (a_1,a_2,...,a_n): a_i \in \mathbb{Z}', n\in\mathbb{N} \} \\
G &= \{ (a_1,a_2,...): a_i \in \mathbb{Z}' \} \\
\\
H &= \{ \{a\} : a\in\mathbb{R}' \} \\
I &= \{ (a;b) : a,b\in\mathbb{R}', a<b \} \\
J &= \{ [a;b] : a,b\in\mathbb{R}', a<b \} \\
K &= \{ (a;a+1) : a\in\mathbb{Z}' \} \\
L &= \{ [a;a+1] : a\in\mathbb{Z}' \} \\
\end{align}$$
For simplicity, we assume that from all these sets we remove elements that have a common part with other elements of this set (so as to use the definition of AC referring to disjoint sets)
Based on each of the above-defined sets (which contain information about a specific subset of $\mathbb{Z}'$ or $\mathbb{R}'$), I would like to generate a set $X$ containing exactly one element from each subset of the given set, e.g. $X_A = \{ a: \exists b \in A, a\in b \} $, or exactly one element from the pair/sequence, e.g., the first element from each pair in $E$ i.e. $X_E = \{ a: \exists b \in E, a\in b \} $
Question
For the generation/creation of which sets $X_A,X_B,X_C,X_D,X_E,X_F,X_G,X_H,X_I,X_J, X_K,X_L$ will I need to use the axiom of choice and why?
Update:
What if $\mathbb {Z}'$ is special set where you cannot compare elements (and find minimal or center element) ? (we exclude cases H-L)

See Axiom of Choice: "It is to be noted that AC for finite collections of sets are both provable (by induction) in the usual set theories. But in the case of an infinite collection, even when each of its members is finite, the question of the existence of a choice function is problematic. For example it is easy to come up with a choice function for the collection of pairs of real numbers (simply choose the smaller element of each pair). 1/2

But it is by no means obvious how to produce a choice function for the collection of pairs of arbitrary sets of real numbers." 2/2

I always saw the axiom of choice as being another one of these pseudo- big deals, like Russell's paradox and Godel incompleteness. You have a handful of paper labels and you walk past a bunch of barrels. They're all full of set elements. You stick one label on one object in each barrel. You can pick the blue ones, you can pick the even numbers, or you can close your eyes and play "pin the tail on the element." There's your choice. You can make it. I can't see how you could ever rationally disallow the axiom of choice.

There are already many questions on this site and others on the merits of constructive mathematics and reasons for rejecting choice; this is a technical question about using the axiom of choice, so this is somewhat off-topic here.

Essentially, this answer is same as answer by Naïm Favier, but more technical.
Axiom of choice can be stated in terms of choice function:
$$\forall S\ \left(\emptyset\notin S\implies (\exists f\colon S\to \bigcup S)(\forall X\in S)\ f(X)\in X\right),$$
which sends each $X\in S$ to one of its elements.
Whether you need axiom of choice to prove existance of a choice function is simply a question whether you can explicitly write formula for at least one choice function or you can't. If you can, then you don't need the axiom, you already have choice function, but if you can't, you can invoke AC to state it's existence even if you have no idea what the function actually is.
To avoid problems with your sets not necessarily having pairwise-disjoint elements, let's simply write a choice function for each of those sets. To get set that you want, take the image of the choice function.
1. sets $A,B,C_n,C,D$
Let's first prove a lemma:

Let $A$ be a well-ordered set and
$S\subseteq \mathcal P(A)\setminus\emptyset$, i.e. $S$ is a subset of power-set of $A$ not containing empty set. Then we can write a choice function
$f\colon S\to \bigcup S$ by formula $f(X) = \min X$.

Proof. This is perhaps more obscure to write down then to prove. Any $X\in S$ is also element of $\mathcal P(A)\setminus \emptyset$, i.e. $X$ is a nonempty subset of well-ordered set $A$, and therefore there exists $\min X\in X.\quad\square$
Now, I will claim that $\mathbb Z'$ can be well-ordered and therefore we can write choice function for all $A,B,C_n,C,D$.
First, let's write down bijection $a\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$
$$a_n = \begin{cases}
-\frac n2,& n\text{ even}\\
\frac{n+1}2,& n\text{ odd}
 \end{cases}$$
which realizes $\mathbb Z = \{a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots\} = \{0,1,-1,2,-2,\ldots\}$, so define a well-ordering $\preceq$ on $\mathbb Z$ by
$$a_n\preceq a_m \iff n\leq m.$$
This gives us a well-ordering of nonempty $\mathbb Z'\subseteq\mathbb Z$ simply by inheritance.
2. sets $E,F_n,F,G$
Under your definitions for tuples, define
\begin{align}
f_E((a,b)) &= a\in (a,b),\\
f_{F_n}((a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)) &= (1,a_1)\in (a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)
\end{align}
and same for others.
3. sets $H,I,J,K,L$
For $I$ and $J$, take $f(\langle a,b\rangle) = \frac{a+b}2\in \langle a;b\rangle$, where $\langle,\rangle$ is either $(;)$ or $[;]$ and the same formula will work for all others as well: for $H$ take $b=a$, for $K,L$ take $b = a+1$.

If $\mathbb Z'$ is arbitrary infinite set, we can't write down explicit choice function for $B$ to $D$ in general, but we can for $E$ to $G$, in the same way as we did above.
There is a famous parallel about choosing shoes and socks from infinitely many pairs. If you have infinitely many pairs of shoes, you can define a choice function by choosing left shoe each time, so we don't need axiom of choice in this case. If you have infinitely many pairs of socks, there is no clear way to distinguish one from another, so we need axiom of choice in this case.
If $\mathbb Z'$ is finite, then you can define well-ordering on $\mathbb Z'$ simply by exausting all of its elements one by one. Axiom of choice is just extension of this reasoning to infinite sets. When it comes to infinity, we can't derive existence of infinite sets from existence of finite ones, so we need axiom of infinity. Similarly, we can well-order finite sets easily, but we can't use that to well-order infinite sets, so we need axiom of choice (which is equivalent to well-ordering theorem).

Edit: In response to comments, let me add this.
Let $X$ be a two element set. In particular it is not empty, so $\exists x\,(x\in X)$ is true. By existential instantiation we can introduce a constant symbol $a_X$ for which we know $a_X\in X$ is true. In simpler terms, we know that there is at least one element in $X$, so we can name an element of $X$ with $a_X$. Now, let $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ be a finite set of two element sets $X_i$. In finite number of steps we can use existential instantiation to produce elements $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ such that $a_i\in X_i$. In that way we produced a choice function $X_i\mapsto a_i\colon \{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\to \bigcup_{i=1}^nX_i$. The problem arises if we have infinite collection $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ because we can only produce finitely many elements $a_i\in X_i$ with the above procedure, so we can't produce choice function since our procedure never terminates. That doesn't mean that there isn't such a function, we just can't prove or disprove it using ZF alone (assuming it is consistant), just like using ZF without axiom of infinity we can't prove or disprove existence of set of natural numbers.
Going back to socks. Finite collection $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ is now all pair of socks in your drawer. Each day you take one pair out of drawer and you choose one to put it on your left foot and after the day ends, you throw it into dirty clothes bin. After $n$ days, you used up all of your pair of socks and now have to wash it. What you did is produce a choice function that picks a sock to put on your left foot out of all of your pair of socks. However, if you lived in a magical land where you had infinitely many pair of socks, you'd never have to wash any, and you'd never finish producing a choice function that picks a sock to put on your left foot for all of your infinitely many pairs.
Contrast this with arbitrary collection $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ where $X_i$ are again two element sets, but this time totally ordered. Now, you can simply define $f\colon \{X_i\}_{i\in I} \to \bigcup_{i\in I} X_i$ by formula $f(X_i) = \min X_i$.
Now, instead of socks, we are considering pairs of shoes. It doesn't matter how many pairs of shoes you have, you don't pick a shoe each day, you can decide ahead (write down a choice function) that each day you will put the left shoe on your left foot.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Assuming excluded middle:
None of $A$, $B$, $C_n$, $C$, require choice since all of their members have a (unique) minimal element.
$D$ doesn't require choice either, as you can always pick the minimal element in absolute value (and if both $a \in S$ and $-a \in S$, pick the positive one).
Similarly, none of $E$, $F_n$, $F$, $G$ require choice since all of their members have a first component.
Similarly, none of $H$, $I$, $J$, $K$, $L$ require choice since all of their members have a "middle element", in the sense of $S \mapsto \frac{\mathrm{inf}(S) + \mathrm{sup}(S)}{2}$.

the definition of AC that I used does not mention anything about a minimal element - so why do you use this concept? What if the sets Z' and R' were sets in which the elements cannot be compared? (and therefore the minimum cannot be defined) (we exclude cases I,J and G)

I am not using AC, so your definition is irrelevant here. I am building a selector set directly. (Or rather, I am showing that AC holds for the specific instances of $S$ in your question.) You said $\mathbb{Z}' \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}' \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, so their elements can be compared using the respective orders from $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

ok, then explain why the possibility of comparing elements (and sometimes ability to find minimal/center element) of a subset means that AC does not have to be used - because it is unclear.

You just pick the minimal element from every set and it gives you a selector set/choice function. This is sometimes called unique choice, non-choice or function comprehension; it's really nothing fancy.

Well then write what the problem is when it is not possible to select the minimum element. Why is selecting any element a problem and do you have to use AC -?

I'm not sure what you mean by "special set", but if nothing is known about $\mathbb{Z}'$ then you need AC in all cases except $A$ (weaker versions of AC might work for some cases).

Correct me if I'm wrong - but from what I've heard, supposedly in every set it is possible to introduce a partial order. And if so, in every set it is possible to determine the minimal element if it exists. So is AC only reserved for cases where the minimal element does not exist?

The only partial order you can meaningfully equip an arbitrary set X with without choice is the discrete partial order (equality), in which case X has a minimal element iff X has a unique element, so you've gained nothing. In case you're thinking of a well-order, then "every set is well-ordered" is equivalent to AC.

Ok, you wrote above in comments: "their elements can be compared using the respective orders from ℤ and ℝ"

and there is one more problem - in the set Z or R one can define infinitely many orders (if I am not mistaken). So how do we know which one to choose to use this order for our selector function selecting the minimal element? We can say that we change the problem of selecting an element in a given subset to the problem of selecting some order (to be able to select an element in a given subset) - ?


Well, I just told you which order to use. I'm the one making the choice here! It's not a particularly far-fetched choice either, as it's just the restriction of the order on $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}'$.

You could pick a different order if you like, and maybe choose the maximal element instead of minimal. The point is that you can write down a definite element of every subset.

You wrote: "The point is that you can write down a definite element of every subset." so the problem is that we use AC because there may be non empty subsets in which it is not possible to select/write a specific element. Explain to me why this problem does not occur when selecting an element from the set of all orders on Z ?

Because you can write down a specific order on $\mathbb{Z}$ (the usual one), and this order canonically restricts to an order on any subset $\mathbb{Z}' \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$.

Thank you for your patience. Last question, please clarify this - Case B where Z' is very big and exotic set - so exotic that actually we cannot explicite write function to compare any two elements {a,b} (because any two different elements are always so exocitc and different that comparison is nontrivial). So in case B witch exotic Z' we need AC to create $X_B$ or not?

Sure; you don't even need $B$ to be that big; some form of choice is required even to choose elements from an $ℕ$-indexed family of two-element sets.
